# Is there any advantage of using MERGE over TRUNCATE/DELETE followed by INSERT INTO SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, merge

I've this code, code #1:

```
MERGE sales.category t 
    USING sales.category_staging s
ON (s.category_id = t.category_id)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        t.category_name = s.category_name,
        t.amount = s.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (category_id, category_name, amount)
         VALUES (s.category_id, s.category_name, s.amount)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE;
```

I can use this instead, Code #2:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sales.category

INSERT INTO sales.category
SELECT * FROM category_staging
```

Or I can use this instead, code #3:

```
DELETE FROM sales.category

INSERT INTO sales.category
SELECT * FROM category_staging
```

Is there any **performance**/**non-performance** advantage of using code #1?

Comment: You should test this. For larger tables, deletes are much slower than inserts. It seems if you were attempting to eliminate repeated deletes then #2 would be more performant. But who knows how many records would need to be deleted during the merge. If your goal is to entirely repopulate a table from a staging table then option #2. For adverse affects on logging and truncate table, here is a good read -> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26782.sql-server-an-examination-of-logging-in-truncate-table-statement-and-its-comparison-with-delete-statement.aspx

Comment: Are you wrapping the TRUNCATE/DELETE blocks in a transaction?  If so, you potentially could have some blocking.  If not, then there is a small window where readers will get no results.